How much of a problem is this rotted joist end and what should I do about it?
I found some surface rot on the last few inches of a floor joist.  It's only 3/4" to 1" deep and the joist is already doubled up.  There is still 1"-2" of solid wood sitting on the beam.  Is this a big problem?  Would rotted wood restorer help and how can I fix it?

Pictures would help us help you. Edit and click on the sun and mountains icon.

I  think I'll need a visual, too, but 1-1/2" is often enough bearing. Note that you don't restore structural framing. Ever. You replace it. Also note that glue applied in the field is never to be considered structural. It's for noise prevention, mostly.

Carve out the rotten part and don't try to restore it,
If the rot is too bad to continue using this joist repair it (using new wood and repair plates/sistering etc) or replace it.

Can you give me a bit more than that?  That's already covered by comments.

no, not really.

Could you please delete this answer?  I'd like to delete the question but I'm not allowed because this is here.
